# Let $U_n$ be the subset of $2\times2$ matrices $M_2(\mathbb C)$ such that $T^n=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, algebraic-geometry

Fixed $n>0$ let $U_n$ be the subset of $2\times2$ matrices $M_2(\mathbb C) \simeq \mathbb C^4 \simeq \mathbb A_{\mathbb C}^4$ such that $T^n=I$.

a) Show that $U_n$ is a Zarisky closed subset of $M_2(\mathbb C)$.

b) Describe the irriducible components of $U_n$ and show that there are $ \binom {n+1} {2}$ of them.

Partial Solution:

a) $U_n$ is given by an ideal $I \subset \mathbb C[a,b,c,d]$ generated by at most 4 polynomials. We are done.

b) ??? I can diagonalize every matrix with eigenvalues $\alpha$, $\beta$ $n$-th roots of $1$. Can't tell more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part b, use the characteristic polynomial and examine how it changes on various classes of matrices. Full solution below.

> The assignment of characteristic polynomials is constant on similarity classes of matrices. Using your diagonalization suggestion, every matrix satisfying $T^n=I$ is similar to $A_{p,q}= \begin{pmatrix} \zeta^p & 0 \\ 0 & \zeta^q\end{pmatrix}$ for integers $0\leq p,q \leq n-1$ and $\zeta$ a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity.

Further,

> The characteristic polynomial of $A_{p,q}$ is $\chi_{p,q}(x)=x^2-(\zeta^p+\zeta^q)+\zeta^{p+q}$. How many possibilities are there for this polynomial based on different choices of $p$ and $q$? If $p\neq q$, then $\chi_{p,q}=\chi_{q,p}$ and no other choices will work, so for $p\neq q$ there are $n(n-1)/2=\frac{n^2-n}{2}$ possible characteristic polynomials. If $p=q$, then there are no choices that are not identical which give the same polynomial, so there are $n$ possible polynomials this way.

And...

> Putting these two cases together, we get $\frac{n^2-n}{2}+n=\frac{n^2-n+2n}{2}=\frac{n^2+n}{2}=\frac{(n+1)n}{2}=\binom{n+1}{2}$.

Comment: I forgot $T$ solves his own characteristic polynomial! Thanks!